# Daemon intended to replace a Cronjob which reads and processes events from a queue

Tags: c++, linux

The Daemon will read the output from a php command line interface, and process events until there are none left in the queue. Consider the sleep timer arbitrary.

At the moment testOutput.php simple logs some strings to the console, some of which contain "EXITCODE-0", meaning there are no events in the queue.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <regex>
// daemon functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <syslog.h>
// logs
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

void logOutput(std::string);

static void daemon();

std::string exec(const char* cmd);

enum EventAction {      eventActioned,
                        eventOne,
                        eventTwo };

static std::map<std::string, EventAction> mapValueToEvent;

void initialise();

int main() {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "bendaemon has started");
    daemon();
    initialise();

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        std::string result = exec("php -f /Users/easysigns/PlayGround/bash/readPhpOutput/testOutput.php");
        switch(mapValueToEvent[result]) {
            case eventOne:
                // process event one
                logOutput("one");
                break;
            case eventTwo:
                // process event two
                break;
            case eventActioned:
                // write some event complete log
                logOutput("zero");
                sleep(20);
                break;
            default:
                // event not defined.  write some error log
                break;
        }
    }

    syslog(LOG_ERR, "Terminating daemon");
    closelog();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
    std::array<char, 4096> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
    if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    while (!feof(pipe.get())) {
        if (fgets(buffer.data(), 4096, pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
            result += buffer.data();
        }
    }
    std::regex expression("EXITCODE-0");
    if(std::regex_search(result, expression) == 1) {
        result = "1";
    }
    else {
        result = "0";
    }
    return result;
}

void initialise() {
    mapValueToEvent["1"] = eventOne;
    mapValueToEvent["2"] = eventTwo;
    mapValueToEvent["0"] = eventActioned;
}

void logOutput(std::string value) {
    std::ofstream logFile;
    logFile.open("/Users/easysigns/PlayGround/bash/readPhpOutput/logFile.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    std::time_t now = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    logFile << "Time: " << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now), "%F %T") <<  " Event success: " << value << std::endl;
    return;
}

static void daemon() {
    pid_t pid; 
    // Fork off the parent process
    pid = fork();
    // An error occurred
    if (pid < 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Success: Let the parent terminate
    if (pid > 0) {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }   
    // On success: The child process becomes session leader
    if (setsid() < 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //TODO: Implement a working signal handler
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
    // Fork off for the second time (detatch from terminal window)
    pid = fork();
    // An error occurred
    if (pid < 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Success: Let the parent terminate
    if (pid > 0) {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    umask(0);
    // This may need to point to a different directory in the future
    chdir("/");
    // Close all open file descriptors
    for (int x = (int)sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX); x >= 0; x--) {
        close (x);
    }
    // Open the log file
    openlog("bendaemon", LOG_PID, LOG_DAEMON);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to comment on the OS interactions here, just the C++ code in general.

### prefer anonymous namespaces to the static keyword

static is just a C backwards compatibility thing, the proper way to prevent a name from leaking out of a translation unit is an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace {
  void daemon();
  std::map<std::string, EventAction> mapValueToEvent;
}
```

### Prefer using enum class to regular enum

```
enum class EventAction {...};
```

This prevents a large number of namespace polution issues, and is just a good habit to build.

### prefer using std::unordered_map to std::map

Unless you have a reallllly good reason, `std::unordered_map` is almost always preferable.

### Why shared_ptr?

```
std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
```

While you get mad props for using RAII to manage the FILE pointer, you should be using a unique_ptr here, not a shared_ptr.

### initialise() is unnecessary

You can simply initialize the map using a literal:

```
static std::map<std::string, EventAction> mapValueToEvent = {
  {"1", eventOne},
  {"2", eventTwo},
  {"0", eventActioned}
};
```

## Logic error, exec() can only return "0" or "1"

That doesn't feel right, since you handle "0", "1" or "2"